# React router only show Navigation component if the current path is on any of the valid routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

For a invalid route, I want to show the `NotFound` component, but also not show the `Navigation` component:

```
const Layout: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navigation />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/explore" exact>
          <ExploreIndex />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/explore/:id" exact>
          <ExploreShow />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/" exact>
          <Home />
        </Route>

        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

If I go to `/aaaaaaa`, my `NotFound` component loads but so does my `Navigation`.  How can I not have `Navigation` render for such routes?

Answer (score 2):

What about just rendering it as another route?

```
<Route path={['/explore', '/explore/:id', '/']} exact component={Navigation} />
```

It will not be rendered if the route does not match any of the routes listed in the `path` array.

Answer (score 0):

You can add NavigationBar in the specific components rather than app.js. So for example if there is a about page, place NavigationBar on top of the component